# Allow PHP login script to access Windows Server user data for authentication purposes on Intranet website

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, login-script

I am developing a project in which I would like to have users log into the website using their username and passwords that are stored on our main Windows 2008 server. I have looked on Google, but I'm not sure that I am searching for the right thing. I have seen this done before plenty of times, so I know it is possible. If anybody could offer any guidance on where to look then that would be great!

Many thanks,

Cobain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you check question: [IIS 7 - Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469197/iis-7-windows-authentication)

look like "IIS PHP windows domain authentication" correct keywords for googling