# Running ASP.NET app in VS 2015 debugger with firefox throws login failed for user: NT AUTHORITY/ANONYMOUS LOGON

Tags: sql, asp.net, debugging, firefox, database-connection

The debug session with VS2015 on my developer workstation works with chrome and connects to the external SQL Server 2012 database from my web app.  I cannot figure out why firefox causes this error while in the debugger in the attempt to make a db connection.

Firefox works otherwise with this web app in IIS from the webserver which by the way also contains the database on the same server when running outside of VS 2015.

What am I missing and why would chrome work but not firefox while debugging in VS 2015 in connecting to the database with integrated security turned on

Everything I see on the internet has to do with this issue when running the web app in IIS and the database on an external server with double hop issues.  My problem is running from the debugger and only firefox not working!  We need to have firefox working for reasons beyond the scope of my question in the debugger.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Thanks!

Here is my connection string from my web.config  (I also tried with Integrated Security=true)

Here is a code snippet where the cmd.Connection.Open() throws the exception

Dim cmd As SqlCommand = GetSqlCommand(GetSelectForBlackPearlPersonal(whereClause, orderBy))

Try
    Using cmd.Connection
    cmd.Connection.Open()
.
.
.
     End Using
 Catch ex As Exception

```
 Throw New Exception("Database issue: " & ex.ToString)
```

End Try

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BP.Properties.Settings.BPConstr" connectionString="Data Source=djwbp38.jcce.dev.com;Initial Catalog=BlackPearl;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 0):

I found in another post that someone set impersonation to false in their web.config.

I just changed the impersonate setting from true to false and now its working on firefox in the debugger

I am baffled....Does anyone know why this would be the case?  thanks! Kevin

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string states:"***Integrated Security=SSPI***". This means that you are using Windows Integrated Authentication.
It allows your Windows users' account credentials (or Active Directory in corporate domains) to pass through their browser to a web server and to SQL Server.

Windows Integrated Authentication is **enabled by default for Internet Explorer but not for Mozilla Firefox**.

**To configure Firefox to use Windows Integrated Authentication:**

1. Open Firefox.
2. In the address bar type about:config
3. You will receive a security warning. To continue, click I’ll be careful, I promise.
4. You will see a list of preferences listed. Find the settings below by browsing through the list or searching for them in the search box. Once you have located each setting, update the value to the following:

> - **network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris**  *MyIISServer.domain.com*
> - **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris** *MyIISServer.domain.com*
> - **network.automatic-ntlm-auth.allow-proxies**    *True*
> - **network.negotiate-auth.allow-proxies** *True*
>     
>     *MyIISServer.domain.com* should be the fully qualified name of your IIS server

Here are some older posts that provide explanation and, hopefully, an answer to your question.

- [Configuring Chrome and Firefox for Windows Integrated Authentication](https://specopssoft.com/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for-windows-integrated-authentication/)
- [Enabling NTLM Authentication (Single Sign-On) in Firefox](https://www.liquidstate.net/enabling-ntlm-authentication-single-sign-on-in-firefox/)
- [Integrated Windows Authentication with IIS, Firefox and SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733237/integrated-windows-authentication-with-iis-firefox-and-sql-server)